# Location getAccuracy() don´t work in GPS

Tags: android, gps

There are to types of locations. Network location and GPS location. In Network location getAccuracy() works ok.

But in GPS location I get locations with getAccuracy() = {5m,10m,15m}. I check locations in map and some times is ok. But in 40% of cases {5m,10m,15m} is real {300m,100m,500m}.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                locationListenerGPS);
```

(...)

```
LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //Process location
        sendLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

};
```

In image of example getAccuracy() = 6.6m and real error is 239.15m

[image]

Comment: This seems to be an incredible bad GPS receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Location#getAccuracy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()) provides an estimate with 68% probability that the location is within the given radius. It cannot be guaranteed that the true location will always be within the accuracy provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to snap those gps coordinates to the road, try the [Google Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap)

It's not as important to have super accurate gps coordinates when using this API.